# How to generate Amazon SQS queue programmatically(ASP.Net) to get AnyOfferChanged notification?

Tags: amazon-sqs

We want to create following things programmatically either through ASP.Net OR through JSON to get AnyOfferChanged notification

1. Create Amazon Standard SQS queue
2. Add permission to generated queue.
3. Create SNS topic
4. Create subscription for topic

Thank You
Raj

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a queue using the AWS .NET SDK: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/index.html?page=SQS/MSQSSQSCreateQueueString.html&tocid=Amazon_SQS_AmazonSQSClient
2. Control access to the queue via IAM policies: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-authentication-and-access-control.html
3. Create SNS topic: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/index.html?page=SNS/MSNSSNSCreateTopicString.html&tocid=Amazon_SimpleNotificationService_AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient
4. Subscribe SQS queue to SNS topic: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/index.html?page=SNS/MSNSSNSSubscribeQueueStringICoreSQSString.html&tocid=Amazon_SimpleNotificationService_AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient